# Upload file on server using Rest API

Tags: java

I want to commit text file `"demo2.txt"` to bitbucket server using rest API. I can upload the same file using Postman but it's not working with Java code. As shown in the below code I want to send string object "str" as the body. Can someone help me here to upload the file on the bitbucket server? Also Please let me know if there is any other way to do this.

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{team name}/{repository name}/src");

HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

httpCon.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-with", "Curl"); 
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setDoInput(true); 
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicauth); 
httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST"); 


String str =
 "{"        
+ "\"-F\":\"File3=@/D:/log/demo2.txt\" "
+ "}";

try { 
    OutputStream output = httpCon.getOutputStream();
    output.write(str.getBytes()); 
    output.close();
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
String inputLine; 
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();                 
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED){
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new . 
    InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream()));               

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
        response.append(inputLine); 
    }                
    in.close();
    List<String> message = new ArrayList<>();
    message.add(response.toString());           
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details about what goes wrong ? Are you catching an Exception ? what's the message ?

Comment: See this link:https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/from-java-do-put-in-bitbucket/19141/2

Comment: I am not getting any error. Response code is 201. Its changing repository access time on bitbucket.org but its not uploading file.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all of your code, then your problem may be as simple as the fact that you're not making any sort of call to finalize the request...to tell HttpURLConnection that you're done forming the request and want it to complete.  There are two things you can do to help this:

1. close the output stream when you're done writing to it.  You're generally supposed to do this.  Here, you can call `output.close()`.  Better still, since you have a try/catch block already anyway, use a "try with resources" construct to make sure that the stream is closed no matter what happens (assuming you're using a newer version of Java that supports this).
2. make some sort of call to query the response to the request.  It may
   be that the request is not being fully sent until you do this.  Try
   calling `httpCon.getResponseCode()` at the bottom of your code.

Given that you have provided no information as to what "it's not working with Java code" means, this may be useful information but not the ultimate solution to your problem.  Your code does look good other than exhibiting these omissions.

Comment: I am not getting any error. Response code is 201. Its changing repository access time on bitbucket.org but its not uploading file

Answer (score 0):

```
    String username = "test";
    String appToken = "********************";//enter your 20 character app password here
    String encodedCredentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username+":"+appToken).getBytes("UTF-8")); //Bitbucket REST API needs the credentials to be Base64 encoded with "UTF-8" formatting
    String repositoryName = "test-java";
    String branchName = "master";
    String filename = "/data/hello.txt";
    String sourceBranch = "master";
    String destinationBranch = "branch-creted-via-java";
    String pullRequestTitle = "master-merge-pr"

static void getFileContentFromRepository(String username, String repositoryName, String branchName, String filename, String encodedCredentials){
   String urlToAccess = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/"+username+"/"+repositoryName+"/src/"+branchName+"/"+filename;
   URL repositoryUrl = new URL (urlToAccess);
   HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) repositoryUrl.openConnection();
   //For authentication
   connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedCredentials); 
   connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
   connection.connect();
   System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode()+" "+connection.getResponseMessage());
   //The InputStream is required to read in the data of the GET request
   InputStream connectionDataStream = connection.getInputStream();
   String connectionStreamData = IOUtils.toString(connectionDataStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   System.out.println(connectionStreamData); 
   //the data can be returned as well, just change the return type of the function to String.
}


static void createBranch(String username, String repositoryName, String sourceBranch, String featureBranch, String filename, String encodedCredentials) throws IOException {
        String urlToAccess = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/"+username+"/"+repositoryName+"/src/";
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToAccess.openConnection();
        //For authentication
        connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedCredentials);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        //OutputStreamWriter is used to set the form data in the post request to create A NEW BRANCH
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write("parents="+sourceBranch+"&branch="+featureBranch);
        out.close();
        try{
            connection.connect();
            System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode()+" "+connection.getResponseMessage());
            System.out.println("Feature Branch "+featureBranch+" created");
        }catch (Exception e){
           System.out.println("Branch creation failed.");
        }
    }


static void createFileInRepository(String username, String repositoryName, String branchName, String data, String filename, String encodedCredentials) throws IOException {
        String urlToAccess = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/"+username+"/"+repositoryName+"/src/";
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToAccess.openConnection();
        //For authentication
        connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedCredentials);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        //For setting the form data in the post request to add a new file and fill it with your data
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write("branch="+branchName+"&"+"/"+filename+"="+data);
        out.close();
        try{
            connection.connect();
            System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode()+" "+connection.getResponseMessage());
            System.out.println("File Created");
        }catch (Exception e){
           System.out.println("File creation failed.");
        }
    }


static void createPR(String username, String repositoryName, String prFromBranch, String prToBranch, String filename, String encodedCredentials, String pullRequestTitle) throws IOException {
        String pullRequestData = String.format("{\"title\":\"%s\",\"source\":{\"branch\":{\"name\":\"%s\"}},\"destination\":{\"branch\":{\"name\":\"%s\"}}}",pullRequestTitle,prFromBranch, prToBranch); //format of data required for rest API call.
        System.out.println(pullRequestData);
        byte[] prRequestData = pullRequestData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int prRequestDataLen = prRequestData.length;
        URL prURL = new URL ("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/"+username+"/"+repositoryName"+/pullrequests");
        HttpURLConnection prConnection = (HttpURLConnection) prURL.openConnection();
        //For authentication
        prConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedCredentials);
        prConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //For setting the metadata in the POST request
        prConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        prConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        prConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",Integer.toString(prRequestDataLen));
        prConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        try(DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(prConnection.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write(prRequestData);
        }
        try{
            prConnection.connect();
            System.out.println(prConnection.getResponseCode()+" "+prConnection.getResponseMessage());
            System.out.println("Pull request created");
        }catch (Exception e){
           System.out.println("Pull request failed.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).